# Alterar Widht e Hight de uma texto em Java usando a Classe Graphics

Tags: java, string, font, awt, graphics

Olá, segue minha duvida.:

Conforme a imagem abaixo gostaria de reproduzir algo assim no Java usando a Classe Graphics quero conseguir dimensionar um texto com o método drawString, dei uma olhada na classe Font porem só consegui adicionar novas fontes e aumentar o tamanho delas porem gostaria de alterar o Widht e Hight do texto separadamente dando esse efeito de letras esticadas, porem infelizmente a classe Font só aceita um int como size encontrei algo sobre uma classe Dimension porem ainda não sei se é bem esse o objetivo dela.

Estou postando minha duvida aqui porem sigo pesquisando caso descubra como antes de me responderem eu darei um retorno, desde já agradeço a atenção.

[image: Exemplo]